# Show only "add" button for formset by default

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this inlineformset_factory in my form that by default shows one extra fieldset even when it's empty.

```
some_formset = inlineformset_factory(ItemObject,
                   ItemObjectExterior,fk_name='obj', extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

But I'd like to show this fieldset only when "add" button is clicked. How can I do that?

If I specify `extra=0` that there's no fieldset shown by default but there's no "add" button either.

Answer (score 0):

I guess two options.

1. Make `extra=0`, and add a separate `form` to your context, which is 
   shown when the button is clicked.
2. They get their own classes. So do something like:
   `$(".form-class:last-child").style("display", "none")`
   Your add button that has something like:
   `$(".form-class:last-child").style("display", "block")`